# How to properly compare command-line arguments?

Tags: c, string, command-line-arguments, string-comparison, strcmp

I am trying to write a C code which takes arguments in main; thus when I write some strings in cmd, the program doing somethings inside it. But I am doing something wrong and I can't find it.

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){   //File name is main.c
    if(argc != 3)
        printf("Wrong!!!!!!!!!");
    else
        if (argv[1] == "-s")
            girls();  //Prints "Girls"
        else if(argv[1] == "-k")
            boys();   //Prints "Boys"
        else
            printf("OMG!!");
}
```

In the cmd;

> `gcc -o gender main.c`
>
> `gender -s pilkington`

I enter that commands. Bu the output is always

> "OMG!!"

Which part is wrong?

Comment: **==** will compare the adresses of the pointers, not the content of the String.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your code, `argv[1] == "-s"` is the erroneous part. comparison of strings cannot be done with `==` operator.

To compare strings, you need to use [`strcmp()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp).

Your code should look like

```
if ( ! strcmp(argv[1], "-s")) { //code here }
```

if you want to check if `argv[1]` contains `"-s"` or not.

Answer (score 2):

Compare the  two strings using the strcmp(s1,s2) function.

```
            if (strcmp(argv[1],"-s")==0)
                    girls();  //Prints "Girls"
            else if(strcmp(argv[1],"-k")==0)
                    boys();   //Prints "Boys"
            else
                    printf("OMG!!");
```

Answer (score 1):

if you check the `argv[1] == "-s"` the condition will not be true. 
since it is a string you can use the strcmp function.

```
     if(( strcmp(argv[1],"-s")) == 0)
     girls();
     else if ((strcmp(argv[1],"-k")) == 0)
     boys();
```

Try this..

Answer (score 0):

You have to compare the string using the strcmp function. You cannot simply check the string 
in equality operator.

```
  int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2);
```

Try this in your code.

```
if ((strcmp(argv[1],"-s")==0)
```